# why reclaimable space from ASMFLASH not show in ASMPROD size in oracle RAC database?

Tags: database, oracle

In my database I have 2 nodes RAC 10g database ,

I want to reclaim some space from flash recovery (ASMFLASH) to my production database (ASMPROD)

I tried the following command :

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE = 50G SCOPE=BOTH SID='*';
```

ASMFLASH size before 65 GB and after execute this command the size changed to 50GB

but still the released space not appear on my production database

How to show and use these 15GB in my production database why its not show ?